# remove or override Content-language header php

Tags: php, nginx

I need to override or remove Content-language header in server responce.

My default headers:

```
Connection:"keep-alive"
Content-Encoding:"gzip"
Content-Language:"ru"
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
Date:"Tue, 20 Oct 2015 08:15:47 GMT"
Server:"nginx"
Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"
X-Powered-By:"PHP/5.4.21"
```

"X-Powered-By" header can be removed  by using

```
header_remove("X-Powered-By");
```

but this dont work for Content-Language.

If header defined in php script by

```
header('Content-Language: uk');
```

server responce header is `Content-Language:"ru,uk"`,

in case:

```
header('Content-Language: uk');
header_remove("Content-Language"); 
header('Content-Language: uk');
```

responce header is same: `Content-Language:"ru,uk"`.

How can I get header `Content-Language:"uk"` without default `ru` value?

Answer (score 0):

headers_sent indicates that it is too late to remove headers. They're already sent. Try  this:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    foreach (headers_list() as $header)
        header_remove($header);
    }
}
header('Content-Language: uk');
```

I am not nginx expert but maybe you need change some settings in nginx like there are php.ini im php.

Comment: only change after this code is Content-Language:"ru,uk", so the "ru" is still present. I dont know what is responsible for Content-Language header, is it nginx or php.